# kafka-connect-jdbc does not fetch consecutive timestamp from source

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I use kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0.jar and postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc41.jar

configuration of connector of kafka connect

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "mode": "timestamp",
  "timestamp.column.name": "updated_at",
  "topic.prefix": "streaming.data.v2",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "connection.user": "user",
  "schema.pattern": "test",
  "query": "select * from view_source",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/test?currentSchema=test"
}
```

I have configured two connectors one source and another sink using the jdbc driver, against a postgresql database ("PostgreSQL 9.6.9")
everything works correctly

I have doubts in how the connector collects the source data, looking at the log I see that between the execution of the queries there is a time difference of 21 seconds

```
11/1/2019 9:20:18[2019-01-11 08:20:18,985] DEBUG Checking for next block of results from TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select * from view_source', topicPrefix='streaming.data.v2', timestampColumn='updated_at', incrementingColumn='null'} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
11/1/2019 9:20:18[2019-01-11 08:20:18,985] DEBUG TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select * from view_source', topicPrefix='streaming.data.v2', timestampColumn='updated_at', incrementingColumn='null'} prepared SQL query: select * from view_source WHERE "updated_at" > ? AND "updated_at" < ? ORDER BY "updated_at" ASC (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier)
11/1/2019 9:20:18[2019-01-11 08:20:18,985] DEBUG executing query select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; to get current time from database (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.JdbcUtils)
11/1/2019 9:20:18[2019-01-11 08:20:18,985] DEBUG Executing prepared statement with timestamp value = 2019-01-11 08:17:07.000 end time = 2019-01-11 08:20:18.985 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier)
11/1/2019 9:20:19[2019-01-11 08:20:19,070] DEBUG Resetting querier TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select * from view_source', topicPrefix='streaming.data.v2', timestampColumn='updated_at', incrementingColumn='null'} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)

11/1/2019 9:20:49[2019-01-11 08:20:49,499] DEBUG Checking for next block of results from TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select * from view_source', topicPrefix='streaming.data.v2', timestampColumn='updated_at', incrementingColumn='null'} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
11/1/2019 9:20:49[2019-01-11 08:20:49,500] DEBUG TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select * from view_source', topicPrefix='streaming.data.v2', timestampColumn='updated_at', incrementingColumn='null'} prepared SQL query: select * from view_source WHERE "updated_at" > ? AND "updated_at" < ? ORDER BY "updated_at" ASC (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier)
11/1/2019 9:20:49[2019-01-11 08:20:49,500] DEBUG executing query select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; to get current time from database (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.JdbcUtils)
11/1/2019 9:20:49[2019-01-11 08:20:49,500] DEBUG Executing prepared statement with timestamp value = 2019-01-11 08:20:39.000 end time = 2019-01-11 08:20:49.500 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier)
```

the first query collects data between 08: 17: 07.000 and 08: 20: 18.985, but the second gathers data between 08: 20: 39.000 and 08: 20: 49.500 .. between both there are 21 seconds of difference in which there may be records ...

```
11/1/2019 9:20:18[2019-01-11 08:20:18,985] DEBUG Executing prepared statement with timestamp value = 2019-01-11 08:17:07.000 end time = 2019-01-11 08:20:18.985 
11/1/2019 9:20:49[2019-01-11 08:20:49,500] DEBUG Executing prepared statement with timestamp value = 2019-01-11 08:20:39.000 end time = 2019-01-11 08:20:49.500
```

I assume that one of the data is the last record obtained and the other value the timestamp of the moment

I can not find an explanation about this
Is the normal operation of the connector?
Should you assume that you are not always going to collect all the information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDBC connector is not guaranteed to retrieve **every** message. For that, you need log-based Change Data Capture. For Postgres that is provided by Debezium and Kafka Connect.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc).

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and wrote the above blog*

Edit: This is now a recording available of the above blog too from ApacheCon 2020:  https://rmoff.dev/no-more-silos

Comment: thank you very much for your response, I value it positively
However, why does the connector not guarantee the transport of each row? neither using the incrementing mode? or timestamp + incrementing?
Should I use Debezium definitely?

Comment: That's an implicit aspect of a polling-based approach, you cannot prevent that more than one update happens between two polling attempts, in which case the first update won't be captured. Log-based CDC as done by Debezium avoids this, as it obtains all the changes from the DBs append-only log files (disclaimer: I'm contributing to Debezium).

Comment: @Gunnar. If I'm using "Incrementing Column" mode only with a JDBC Connector and I'm polling every 1 hour for example, is there a reason to believe that I will ever miss any new records?

Comment: (1/2) I agree this is a great question.  For example, if the connector runs at 13:30:01 but the most recent row in the table has time 13:29:40, I think  you should be fine, as the subsequent run will query `WHERE my_timestamp_col > '...13:29:40'`.  Right?

Comment: (2/2) However, if if the connector runs at 14:30:01 and the most recent row in the table has timestamp 14:30:01, and then after the connector runs a new row is written, also with timestamp 14:30:01.  This new row will be missed in the 14:30:01 run, because it didn't exist till a fraction of a second later, and then it will be skipped in the subsequent run, because this later run will have `WHERE my_timestamp_col > '14:30:01'` on it, right?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Why doesn't the Kafka JDBC connector then not use WHERE my_timestamp_col >= '14:30:01' to also capture the events which appeared at 14:30:01 in between?

Comment: Because the connector supplies the WHERE clause and uses greater than, not greater than or equal. Why? Maybe Robin Moffitt can answer.

Comment: True, but at least there should be an option for greater than or equal. In that case, you may get duplicates, but at least you won't miss anything.